# Terraform provisioner connection user/key

Tags: chef-infra, provisioning, terraform

Terraform gives the provisioner (in my case, chef) the configuration for connection, I set the connection with instance default account, while for security reason, i remove the default account from sudoer.

Then chef has a security behavior, it will remove the validator key after provisionning, such action needs sudo. As the removal of default account from sudo, the operation fails.

The solution could be

- providing multiple users for provisioner connection in terraform,
- disable the chef validator key removal behavior

Anyone has idea for such weird case? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One stupid solution I can figure out for the moment, is:

Before chef provision, I do a pre-provision which create an authorized account, then use such account for chef provision. Not elegant, but will try first.

Comment: As it stands this isn't a viable answer likely to help anyone else who has the same problem as you. You should edit your question to provide more useful information (such as expanding on what you are wanting to happen, what you are currently doing and why that doesn't solve your problem) and then, if you have actually solved your problem, you should edit this answer to explain exactly how to solve the much clearer question you have now created.